# TortoiseHg / Mercurial Can't Synchronize With Existing Repositories After Upgrading

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Currently have version 3.7.2 (on Windows 7 64-bit) and am able to synchronize multiple repos. After upgrading to 3.9.1, workbench is unable to sync any of them. The log shows:

> cmdserver: Process failed to start: No such file or directory

-or-

> cmdserver: process exited unexpectedly with code 0

The 3.8.1 release notes have the following under improvements:

> paths: always respect the HG environment variable

I checked the path environment variable and it's pointing to the correct location.

Are there TortoiseHg / Mercurial setting changes that need to be made? Is there a way to get more detailed info from the log?

**Edit Jan 25, 2018**: Was able to install TortoiseHG 4.4.2 and pull incoming changes after deleting the `%HG%` environment variable.

Comment: I've updated to 3.9.2 from 2.7 and had the same behavior. TortoiseHG did not work, but hg command-line works well. I just downgraded to v 2.7 and will not update it until I **really** need it.

Comment: Just tried again with 4.4.2 and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to delete the `%HG%` environment variable.

I posted my issue on TortoiseHG's Bitbucket and they were quick to respond with that recommendation. ([issue link](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5021/process-failed-to-start-on-synchronizing))

My `%HG%` was pointing to `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg`